# How to implement Socketio in nextjs App router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, socket.io

## How to implement this using Nextjs 13 App Router and Socket.io

*I copied everything but I have a problem with the socketio.ts file*

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nextjs-socketio-chat-piffv?file=%2Fsrc%2Fpages%2Fapi%2Fsocketio.ts%3A1%2C1)

**socketio.ts**

```
import { NextApiRequest } from "next";
import { NextApiResponseServerIO } from "src/types/next";
import { Server as ServerIO } from "socket.io";
import { Server as NetServer } from "http";

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponseServerIO) => {
  if (!res.socket.server.io) {
    console.log("New Socket.io server...");
    // adapt Next's net Server to http Server
    const httpServer: NetServer = res.socket.server as any;
    const io = new ServerIO(httpServer, {
      path: "/api/socketio",
    });
    // append SocketIO server to Next.js socket server response
    res.socket.server.io = io;
  }
  res.end();
};
```

**here is my version **

api/socket/route.ts

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { NextResponseServerIO } from "@/app/types/next";
import { Server as ServerIO } from "socket.io";
import { Server as NetServer } from "http";

export const config = {
api: {
bodyParser: false,
},
};

export async function GET(req: Request, res: NextResponseServerIO) {

    if (!res.socket.server.io) {
          console.log("New Socket.io server...");
          // adapt Next's net Server to http Server
          const httpServer: NetServer = res.socket.server as any;
          const io = new ServerIO(httpServer, {
              path: "/api/socket",
              // addTrailingSlash: false
          });
          // append SocketIO server to Next.js socket server response
           res.socket.server.io = io;
      }
      return NextResponse
}
```

the error show "polling.js:298
GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OkUN45A 404 (Not Found)"